# Getting path of selected folder in VB6

Tags: vb6, common-dialog

I want to get the selected folder path

```
dlgBrowse.ShowOpen
fname = dlgBrowse.FileName
dlgBrowse.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|Log File (*.log)|*.log||All Files (*.*)|*.*"
dlgBrowse.DialogTitle = "Open Log File"
dlgBrowse.ShowOpen
If dlgBrowse.FileName <> "" Then
    txtLogFile.Text = dlgBrowse.FileName
End If
MsgBox fname
```

This shows the output `"C:\MRMS\Report\xyz.txt"`, but I want only the selected folder path, ie if the user selects only root(MRMS) folder i.e. `"C:\MRMS"` or any other folder only up to user selected folder.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way:

```
Dim FullPath as string, ParentFolder as string, l() as string
FullPath = "" '... Write here the path from ComDlg
l = Split(FullPath, "\")
l(UBound(l)) = ""
ParentFolder = Join(l, "\")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Function GetRootDir(ByVal inputString As String) As Integer
    'min real path is c:\.  We need a len of at least 2
    If Len(inputString) < 2 Then
        GetRootDir = ""
    End If
    Dim t As Integer, s As Integer

    t = InStr(1, inputString, "\")
    If t < 1 Then
        GetRootDir = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    s = InStr(t + 1, inputString, "\")
    'If this is the root folder that was selected
    If s < 1 Then
        GetRootDir = Mid(inputString, t + 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetRootDir = Mid(inputString, t + 1, s - t - 1)
End Function
```

Then, in your code, reference the function like this...

```
txtLogFile.Text = GetRootDir(dlgBrowse.FileName)
```

Comment: Change `As Integer` to `As String` ;).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to find the folder of selected file by Common Dialogue is this:

```
FilePath = Replace(CommonDialog1.FileName, "\" & CommonDialog1.FileTitle, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bare-bones solution for VB5 which doesn't have the Split function:

```
    For Num = Len(CommonDialog1.filename) To 4 Step -1
    Charac = Mid$(CommonDialog1.filename, Num, 1)
    If Charac = "\" Then Exit For
    Next
    LastSlashPos = Num
    LastPath = Left$(CommonDialog1.filename, LastSlashPos)
```